# Android studio BLE indication does not work (but notification is working)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing a project that works with the device, when the notification is connected, the data arrives perfectly and everything works, but when the indication is connected, the program does not even enter onCharacteristicChanged

Start indication or notification:

```
public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled) {

        Log.d(TAG, "I was in notificator");

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }

        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
                UUID.fromString(getString(R.string.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG)));

        int properties_local = characteristic.getProperties();
        if (Utils.hasIndicateProperty(properties_local) != 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Indication on this characteristic");
        }
        if (Utils.hasNotifyProperty(properties_local) != 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification on this characteristic");
        }
        else Log.d(TAG, "Notification are NOT on this characteristic");
        byte [] indi = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE;
        byte [] noti = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE;

        if (Activity_BTLE_Services.SWITCHED == 0) {
            if (enabled) {
                boolean a = descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
                Log.d(TAG, "ENABLE INDICATION " + a);
            }
            else {
                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            }
        }

        else {
            if (enabled) {
                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            }

            else {
                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            }
        }

        boolean answer = mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(answer));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "To short time");
        }

        /*try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "To short time");
        }*/

        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor, BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
    }
```

We connect the notification, and then we give a command to another characteristic of the device to change the data (pauses are needed so that the device has time to process the data)

```
else {
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic_fourth = characteristics_ArrayList.get(2);
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic_fifth = characteristics_ArrayList.get(3);
                    btn_scan = findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
                    image_view = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
                    GraphView graph = (GraphView) (findViewById(R.id.graph));
                    graph.removeAllSeries();
                    list.clear();
                    mBTLE_Service.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic_fifth, true);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "To short time");
                    }
                    byte[] data_local = {11, 0};
                    characteristic_fourth.setValue(data_local);
                    mBTLE_Service.writeCharacteristic(characteristic_fourth);
                    btn_scan.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_pause_24);
                    image_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
```

[An example of how it works in nrf connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfuDp.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what is going on in your case, but note the following:

1. It is the `writeDescriptor` method of the `BluetoothGatt` object that actually sends the notification/indication setting to the remote device. If you use the overload that takes a byte array, that is the value to be sent. If you use the overload that takes no byte array, the value set previously using `setValue` will be used.
2. The `setCharacteristicNotification` method tells the bluetooth stack on the local device to forward notifications and indications to the app, if they are received from the remote device.
3. Not sure what your `Thread.sleep` calls are supposed to do. It's generally better to use a Handler and schedule work in the future than blocking a thread in case you want to do something in the future.
4. It appears from the flow in your code that you don't follow the (undocumented) rules that only one GATT operation can be in progress at a time, per `BluetoothGatt` object. It seems that, when the line `mBTLE_Service.writeCharacteristic(characteristic_fourth);` is called, the earlier `writeDescriptor` call is still pending. You must wait for the `onDescriptorWrite` callback before you can send another GATT operation.
5. Make sure the remote device actually sends an indication. You can inspect the packet logs to see what's going on.